# Can you take the Recover Action outside of combat?

Tags: healing, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

In *Mutants and Masterminds 3E*, there is a [Recover Action](http://www.d20herosrd.com/9-gamemastering/8-action-adventure/#TOC-RECOVER-STANDARD-ACTION) that lets one use a Standard action during an encounter to heal your worst condition, but only once per encounter. Recovery outside of combat takes much longer, about a minute of dedicated rest. In a game I'm running via PbP, we're operating on a turn structure due to time pressures (bomb goes off after three minutes), and one of the players tried using a Recover action to recover from Fatigue from an Affliction.

In a situation where there is no actual combat going on currently, but there is a time limit, does it make sense to allow the Recover Action? Maybe allow one for the entire segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using combat rounds for a scene, and someone wants to spend a standard action on Recover, then it should be fine. Recover is limited to once per encounter, and non-combat encounters are still encounters and the limit would still apply.

For your example "bomb scene", the character shouldn't be able to Recover more than once during that scene, even if it is 30 rounds long. But he should be able to Recover that once.

It's probably not the best use of his time, those "time bombs" tend to be instantly fatal, but that's a separate issue.